# Adding Hero Cards cause messages to hang with Skype

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-functions

I have a class in my bot service that returns tasks in a carousel of hero cards.  I find that when debugging locally this works and when using the test client on the azure portal, it works as well.  However, with Skype I find that after a few calls to the same feature "get all tasks", the bot never returns the response message.  The first few times it will work.  The user's request message will say "sending" then "sent" but the bot will never respond.

```
    var tasksFound = false;

    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    var message = context.MakeMessage();
    message.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
    message.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;

    foreach (var contact in contacts)
    {
        if (contact.Tasks.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var task in contact.Tasks)
            {
                if (task.Completed == false)
                {
                    tasksFound = true;

                    var cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();

                    var plButtonComplete = new CardAction()
                    {
                        Value = $"buttonevent,task,complete,{contact.id},{task.Id}",
                        Type = "postBack",
                        Title = "Complete"
                    };

                    cardButtons.Add(plButtonComplete);

                    var plButtonDelete = new CardAction()
                    {
                        Value = $"buttonevent,task,delete,{contact.id},{task.Id}",
                        Type = "postBack",
                        Title = "Delete"
                    };

                    cardButtons.Add(plButtonDelete);

                    var plCard = new HeroCard()
                    {
                        Title = contact.FullName,
                        Subtitle = $"Due: {task.DueDate.ToString("MMM dd")}",
                        Text = $"{task.Description}",
                        Buttons = cardButtons
                    };

                    message.Attachments.Add(plCard.ToAttachment());
                }
            }
            stringBuilder.AppendLine("");
        }
    }
```

I have tried removing all the card functionality and a simple stringbuilder that assembles the message works fine in Skype and the test clients.

Is there something I am missing?  I made sure to use the context.Wait call in the DispatchDialog up the call stack.  Also pretty certain I have all my awaits, etc.

Comment: How many cards are you using? Skype will throw an exception if there are more than ten.

Comment: In this case, there is only one or two cards in the carousel.  However, this brings up a good test case, as we have not tried it with enough to cause skype to have an exception.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your issue.  are you able to put your project in a repo so we can take a look?

Comment: @JasonSowers I can provide access to the repo, it is hosted on VSO so I guess please provide an account that can access that?